# Show that the Kelvin transformation is a diffeomorphism and find the inverse

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, potential-theory

> > Let $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{B}_R(0)$ with $R>0$ and $n>1$. We call $\phi\colon\Omega\to G:=B_R(0)\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ with
> >     $$
> > y=\phi(x):=\frac{R^2}{\lVert x\rVert^2}x\text{ for }\lVert x\rVert > R
> > $$
> >     the Kelvin transformation (relating to the sphere $S_R(0)$). Show, that the Kelvin transformation $\phi\colon\Omega\to G$ is a diffeomorphism and find the Inverse of $\phi$.
> >     **Hint**: clever use of n-dimensional ball coordinates

**Edit** Now I show you my idea.

Here is my idea how to show that:

The transformation does only change the distance from $x$ to the origin.

So when I use ball coordinates, only the first coordinate (which is the radius) changes:

If the radius is $R'>R$ before the transformation, it is $R^2/R'$ after the transformation.

So one can write the Kelvin-transformation in n-dim. ball coordinates as follows

$$
\phi(\varphi(R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1})):=\varphi(R^2/R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1})
$$
where $R'>R$ and $x=\varphi(R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1})$i.e $\varphi$ describes the transformation to n-dim- ball coordinates.

I think with this it is not that difficult to show that the Kelvin-transformation is a diffeomorphism and to find its inverse.

It is

$$
\phi(\varphi(R^2/R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1}))=\varphi(R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1})
$$

so $\phi=\phi^{-1}$ and therefore $\phi$ is bijective.

Then $\phi=\varphi\circ T$ with

$$
T\colon (R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1})\longmapsto (R^2/R',\Phi_1,\ldots,\Phi_{n-1}).
$$

Because all component functions of $T$ are continiously differentiable, and the transformation $\varphi$ is continiously differentiable,too, $\phi=\varphi\times T$ as a composition of two functions that are continiously differentiable, is also continiously differentiable.

So $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and $\phi=\phi^{-1}$.

Am I right?

Comment: It was really necessary to create two new tags?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that it is a problem to create new tags.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\phi( \phi(x))= \frac{R^2}{||\phi(x)||^2} \phi(x)= \frac{R^2}{||\frac{R^2}{||x||^2}x||^2}  \cdot \frac{R^2}{||x||^2}x = \frac{R^2||x||^4}{R^4 ||x||^2} \cdot \frac{R^2}{||x||^2}x = x$$

Comment: Okay, this shows the bijectivity. It remains to show, I think, that f is differentiable continiously. Do I here need the hint to use the n-dim ball coordinates?